# How can i make my carrot on a stick switch my armour to something different when right clicked?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how I could make my "molten iron sword" (a carrot on a stick)
change my "Strong iron armor" (Iron armor with CustomModelData of 2 and other nbt properties) into my "Molten Iron Armour" (Iron Armor with a CustomModelData of 1 and other nbt properties) by right-clicking and also changing back to "Strong iron armor" when right-clicked for a second time (With Molten Iron Armour on).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a a scoreboard objective that keeps track of uses of carrots on a stick with this command:

```
/scoreboard objectives add carrots minecraft.used:minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick
```

You could then execute these commands in a function that executes every tick:

```
#tag players with strong armor who used a carrot on a stick
tag @a[scores={carrots=1..},nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:iron_boots",<strong NBT>},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:iron_leggings",<strong NBT>},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",<strong NBT>},{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:iron_helmet",<strong NBT>}]}] add strongArmor

#tag players with molten armor who used a carrot on a stick
tag @a[scores={carrots=1..},nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:iron_boots",<molten NBT>},{Slot:101b,id:"minecraft:iron_leggings",<molten NBT>},{Slot:102b,id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",<molten NBT>},{Slot:103b,id:"minecraft:iron_helmet",<molten NBT>}]}] add moltenArmor

#set the armor of any player who used a carrot on a stick and has the moltenArmor tag to strong armor
replaceitem entity @a[tag=moltenArmor] armor.head <strong helmet>
replaceitem entity @a[tag=moltenArmor] armor.chest <strong chestplate>
replaceitem entity @a[tag=moltenArmor] armor.legs <strong leggings>
replaceitem entity @a[tag=moltenArmor] armor.feet <strong boots>

#set the armor of any player who used a carrot on a stick and has the strongArmor tag to molten armor
replaceitem entity @a[tag=strongArmor] armor.head <molten helmet>
replaceitem entity @a[tag=strongArmor] armor.chest <molten chestplate>
replaceitem entity @a[tag=strongArmor] armor.legs <molten leggings>
replaceitem entity @a[tag=strongArmor] armor.feet <molten boots>

#remove the tags
tag remove @a strongArmor
tag remove @a moltenArmor

#set the scoreboard objective "carrots" back to 0 for all players
scoreboard players set @a carrots 0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97623/discussion-on-answer-by-bearb001-how-can-i-make-my-carrot-on-a-stick-switch-my-a). If you need to better specify the requirements of your question, edit your question, but not in a way that invalidates current answers or makes the question too broad.